# Does an inverse function always give an identity element?

Tags: group-theory, inverse

So for multiplication the inverse element is 1 over the number and gives 1 which is the identity element for the multiplication operation. Are there examples of operations where there is an inverse function which gives the same result for each element in the group but said result is not an identity element (e.g. an "inverse" which when multiplied by a number gives a number not equal to 1). If these inverses don't exist then why?

Comment: The definition of an inverse relies on the existence of an identity element.

Comment: The question is a little hard for me to follow. Let's take the group of integers under addition to be our group. We can always find an $x$ to solve the equation $a + x = 2$ for any $a \in \Bbb Z$ (the inverse of $a$ solves $a + x = 0$, $0$ being the identity element). Are you asking if equations like this are always solvable?

Comment: @pjs no, I'm asking if there's ever an operation in a group where a o x = b where b is not the identity element so from addition say an inverse where a+x=1

Comment: And you want *the same* $x$ for all group elements $a$?

Comment: @pjs No, for addition x = -a to give the identity element of 0 hence all x are not the same but I do want the same b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think the question comes from the idea that for all $g$, there's some $g^{-1}$ such that $g \circ g^{-1} = e$, where $e$ is the identity element of the group.

Maybe we could call $g^{-1}$ "the (right-)inverse of $g$ with respect to $e$" because right-multiplying $g$ by $g^{-1}$ gives $e$ (I don't know if there's a phrase for this kind of thing, since the identity element is baked into the definition of inverse elements). I think your question is asking if there are "(right-)inverses of $g$ with respect to any fixed group element $b$", that is, some $x$ with $g \circ x = b$ for any $g$ and fixed $b$.

---

Thus, as I understand the question:

> Suppose $G$ is a group with operation $\circ$, and fix $b \in G$.
>
> For each $g \in G$, can we find some $x$ so that $g \circ x = b?$

Yes, this is possible. If you've talked about Cayley tables, this is basically the observation that each group element shows up in each row and each column exactly once (in particular, $b$ shows up in each row exactly once).

In any group, you can solve the equation $g \circ x = b$ by left-multiplying each side by $g^{-1}$ to get the desired value $x = g^{-1} \circ b$. A similar technique will show that $x \circ g = b$ always has a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

The identity element $e$ of a group $(G,\circ)$ is defined by
$$\forall\; g\in G: g\circ e = g = e\circ g$$
The inverse element $g^{-1}$ of an element $g$ of a group $(G,\circ)$ is defined by
$$g^{-1}\circ g = e = g\circ g^{-1}$$
**For a group, the above statement is true for all $g\in G$. However, if given some other operation $\star\neq\circ$ on $G$, we could have $g\star g^{-1}\neq e$, because $e$ means the identity element in respect to $\circ$ and $g^{-1}$ means the inverse in respect to $\circ$.** For example, $2\cdot\frac{1}{2}=1$, but $2+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{2}\neq 1$.

Note that "Inverse" needs "identity element", not the other way around. A set with a binary operation that has an identity element but not an inverse for every element is no group but a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

The inverse $g^{-1}$ is unique for each $g\in G$ (this can be proved). Therefore, given element $g,h,x\in G$, one can always solve the equation $h\circ x = g$ for $x$, it is $$h^{-1}\circ (h\circ x) = (h^{-1}\circ h)\circ x = e\circ x = x \stackrel{!}{=} h^{-1}\circ g$$

Comment: Is it possible for g o g^-1 = b where b is not e to be true (sorry I haven't figured out LaTeX yet)

Comment: @andrew I hope my edit clarified everything?

Comment: @andrew Also check https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ;)

Comment: yeah thanks for the help, been trying to teach myself about groups, definitely better off after this.